# Getting full unskipped data when skip is applied (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My MongoDB database has 80,000+ and will grow into tens of millions soon.
I'm basically implementing pagination like this: `Collection.find({...}).skip().limit()`.

I get this paginated data successfully. But is there a way I can access the full (unpaginated) data without running the query again? I need to do this for caching purposes.
Thank you.

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Access where/how? I think the answer here is "no" because the client never received that data and the database won't keep a cursor opened if it returned all of the requested results. Can you clarify a bit further what you mean when you say that you need it for catching purposes?

Comment: I meant 'caching' (as in using Redis), not 'catching'.
What I'm asking is... is it possible to somehow reference the full unpaginated results even when .skip() and .limit() are applied?

Comment: Sorry - typo from my phone. Got it.  The answer is no for the reasons outlined above, basically there is nothing to reference